# create grid like excel in asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I am a beginner in Asp.net and I am confronted with a problem in the development of my site.
At this stage my database contains information entered by the user:

- The different cities whee sales were made
- The name of the sellers by cities
- The number of sale per article for each seller

Traditionally my company uses excel to create a table that contains sellers organized by city and their sales by article. Below and the left row of the table are calculated column (the totals by articles, by cities/sellers).
I am asked to reproduce this table on my website so that it can generate it automatically.

I searched a little on google and tested a few tricks but nothing answered what I desire to do exactly. i managed to add grids with GridMVC and jquery.database.
 If someone has had to do a kind of stuff or can help me in any way for this, it will be perfect.
Thanks for all help.

Comment: There is a lot you ask... what have you tried? Since you say there is a database i am guessing it would not be difficult to convert it to a table on your website. Exporting to excel or word is also doable. Break your problem down, maybe just get the web stuff going then move on to exporting to excel or word. For Excel or Word you will need to import some libraries, either from MS itself if you have Office on the machine or a third party library. Check out... [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi JohnG,

Sorry if I ask several questions in one, and thanks to your help. What is making me confused i think is calculated column. I managed to add grids with GridMVC and jquery.dataTables library. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include grid in your website then you can use [Jquery datatable](https://datatables.net/). For export purpose you can use tools such as Rotativa or iTextsharp.